# Angular web page needs refresh to load completely

Tags: html, angular, router

I have an angular 7 web app. As an example, when I log in, `routerLink` will redirect me to a page with header(menu), content and footer. I need to refresh that page once to load completely. Header is not loaded.

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

From header html, ts:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.authenticate = this.authService.checkLogin();
  this.isDoctor = this.authService.checkDoctor();
}
```

```html
---------some sort of code----------
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3" *ngIf="authenticate && !isDoctor">
```

I don`t think is relevant, the problem persists without ngIf.

Comment: You saying without `*ngIf` your header component doesn't display? Then something else is going on that we don't know given the amount of information on the question.

Comment: No, header is not loaded rather with ```*ngIf or without. It`s loaded only after refreshing the page.

Comment: There's not enough details to know what's going on, your best bet is to comment stuff out and start basic like very basic by just only have your header component everything else is commented out.